# How to get verified status of Facebook user

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, ios6, xcode4.6

I fellowed **HelloFacebookSample** to retrieve **verified** status from user account, using Facebook SDK for iOS.

I tried to retrieve from **user** instance in the below method. But it seems its not defined
there.

How could I retrieve **verified** status?

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    // here we use helper properties of FBGraphUser to dot-through to first_name and
    // id properties of the json response from the server; alternatively we could use
    // NSDictionary methods such as objectForKey to get values from the my json object
    self.labelFirstName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@!", user.first_name];
    // setting the profileID property of the FBProfilePictureView instance
    // causes the control to fetch and display the profile picture for the user
    self.profilePic.profileID = user.id;
    self.loggedInUser = user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    // here we use helper properties of FBGraphUser to dot-through to first_name and
    // id properties of the json response from the server; alternatively we could use
    // NSDictionary methods such as objectForKey to get values from the my json object
    self.labelFirstName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@!", user.first_name];
    // setting the profileID property of the FBProfilePictureView instance
    // causes the control to fetch and display the profile picture for the user
    self.profilePic.profileID = user.id;
    self.loggedInUser = user;

    NSLog(@"userInfo %@",[user objectForKey:@"verified"]);

}
```

Comment: I am getting null using this.Do we need to add any extra permission for login?